How to display tooltip for sprites using "Handling Sprite Events" in Autodesk Forge Viewer?
I have successfully created my sprites on the viewer via https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/examples/sprites/handling_sprite_events/
But, could not manage to display tooltips for the clicked sprites. I also looked at the code and tracked the functions using below project. But still I could not find out what the 'onSensorClicked' function is doing. Also, when I open the live demo version (https://aps-iot-extensions-demo.autodesk.io/), there is no tooltip implemented for the sprites. Could you please clarify the 'onSensorClicked' function and provide some solution for implementing the tooltip for sprites.
https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo/blob/464ce80637b8e258c1499a4569f53ab1aeb65203/public/extensions/SensorSpritesExtension.js#LL26C38-L26C81

Tooltips are not provided out-of-the-box. In the original (now deprecated) Hyperion demo, tooltips were implemented in the React app that the viewer was embedded in.
If you want to overlay any kind of custom HTML "floating" on top of the viewer, we have other code samples that you can look at for reference, for example, https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-digital-twin/blob/develop/public/scripts/extensions/issues.js#L79-L89.

I made one tooltip component for DataViz. You can tweak the codes and migrate it to your project. (note. Please ignore BIM360-prefix, as it was a part of my BIM360 Assets Sample)
Here, it demonstrates how to use it in the sprite-clicked event:
onSensorClicked(event) {

    if (event.clickInfo && this.dbId2DeviceIdMap) {
        const deviceId = this.dbId2DeviceIdMap[event.dbId];

        const { sensors } = this.dataProvider;
        if (!sensors || sensors.length <= 0) return;

        const sensor = sensors.find(s => s.externalId == deviceId);

        if (!sensor) return;

        this.tooltip.show(sensor);
    } else {
        this.tooltip.hide();
    }
}

this.viewer.addEventListener(
    Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.MOUSE_CLICK,
    this.onSensorClicked
);


https://github.com/yiskang/forge-bim360-assets.viewer/blob/bim360-iot-connected/bim360assets/wwwroot/js/BIM360IotConnectedExtension.js#L300
https://github.com/yiskang/forge-bim360-assets.viewer/blob/bim360-iot-connected/bim360assets/wwwroot/css/main.css#L182

